# Can I restrict multiple files in an url at once with joomla htacess (the end of the path are usernumbers)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I apologize if i am not in the right place. But I have a spam problem that i am trying to solve. I will try to explain it.

My website (joomla) gets a lot of traffic on this path:

`http://www.lwbsmile.nl/component/k2/itemlist/user/1448` (last number is the usernumber which is variable, as you can see there are a lot). Users can't login and can't register, i made sure of that. Still they can go to that path.

Let's say that ^ stands for all present and future users. Is there a way of addressing all that users at once and restrict all present and future users?

to make it visual... and this is probably wrong, but something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^/component/k2/itemlist/user/^ [R=403,L]
```

I am not really good with this stuff, but it would really be appreciated if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `F` (Forbidden) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^component/k2/itemlist/user/\d* - [F,L]
```

Comment: The result should be instant right? I don't see a change yet. What does \d* exactly means?

Comment: @user3660755 Where did you put the htaccess file? And what other rules are there?

Comment: it is in the website root folder,  https file. other rules are  mod rewrite in use, redirects, expire headers, blocking of bots with rewrite (that i am not sure about if it works). I will come back to it tomorrow.I am sorry I can't be clearer to you. just trying to solve a spam problem...

Comment: Put the rule above everything else. Just after `RewriteEngine On` statement.

Comment: THANK YOU SO SO SO VERY MUCH hjpotter92. this works!! I have been trying for so long and now it works.. I can't thank you enough for this really, you made my day!

Comment: @user3660755 Please mark this answer as selected and the question will stop appearing under unanswered questions list. =) Thanks